# Future in the Past Negative Question

Tags: grammar

- Was I not going to clean?

Is this question grammatically correct?. If not how can I ask this question without use "wasn’t"?

Comment: It's grammatical but what is your intended meaning? At least in American English, "Was I not going to ...?" doesn't have quite the same meaning as "Wasn't I going to...?" In the first question, you are asking if you did not plan to do something. In the second question, you are asking if you did plan to do it.

Comment: "Wasn't I going to clean the room?" ->I am trying to ask if I did plan to clean the room in this question. I want to learn how can I write this question without contraction(wasn't). 

-Was I not going to clean the room? -> Is it correct?

Comment: If you are trying to avoid "Wasn't", the question "Was I going to clean the room?" has essentially the same meaning as "Wasn't I going to clean the room?" In the 1st question, you are asking yourself if you were going to clean the room, the 2nd implies that you thought you were going to clean the room, but need confirmation. It makes more sense in the 2nd person. "Were you going to clean the room" vs. "Weren't you going to clean the room?"

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to avoid "wasn't/weren't" and I understood, "Was I going to clean the room?" has essentially the same meaning as "Wasn't I going to clean the room?". But I just try to learn where is "not" place in a negative question sentence. For this question:
"Weren't you going to clean the room?" Which sentence is grammatically correct and has the same meaning?
1- Were you not going to clean the room?
2- Were you going to not clean the room?

Comment: "Were you not going to clean the room" could mean the same as "Weren't you going to clean the room" (i.e., I thought you were planning to clean the room), but it's tricky because if there is emphasis on "not"⁠—"Were you NOT going to clean the room?"⁠—then it could mean the same as "Were you going to not clean the room" (i.e, was it always your plan not to clean the room?)

Comment: I really appreciate your patience and answers. Thank you so much.